# Periodic output via bash

Tags: bash

I have input like:

```
fu
ba
wm
20
14
```

and want to get this output:

```
fu # new period
fu
ba
ba
fu
fu
ba # new period
ba
wm
wm
ba
ba
wm # new period
wm
20
20
wm
wm
20 # new period
20
14
14
```

the periodic behaviour is this:

```
n
n
n+1
n+1
n
n

n+1
n+1
n+2
n+2
n+1
n+1
```

I tried it with awk:

```
echo -e "0\n1\n2" | awk 'p;p{print $1}{p=$1};p;p'
```

which isn't working properly.

Any help is apreciated.

Comment: Define _periodic output_.  Elaborate.

Comment: Can you clarify your logic to get that output?

Comment: `echo -e "0\n1\n2" | ( read; echo -e "0\n0\n1\n1\0\n0\n1\n1\n2\n2\n1\n1\n2\n2"`) would produce that output from that input. It's not at all clear how the output is supposed to relate to the input in general, though.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I gave further output now. @twalberg I want to use a script because I need to produce a lot of lines and by hand this is quite boring...

Comment: Why did you guys close the question? I did edit with further information, see the minimal example and the description of the desired behaviour. There is even an accepted answer, so there are people understanding the question. I vote to re-open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, perhaps something like this:

```
( read first
  while read second
  do
    echo -e "${first}\n${first}\n${second}\n${second}\n${first}\n${first}"
    first=${second}
  done
) < input.txt
```

Or, in `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1{prev=$0}NR>1{printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", prev, prev, $0, $0, prev, prev; prev=$0}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With awk you can do it like this:

```
$ awk '{a[NR]=$1} END{for (i=1;i<NR;i++) for (j=0;j<=2;j++) printf "%s\n%s\n", a[i+j%2],a[i+j%2]}'  file
fu
fu
ba
ba
fu
fu
ba
ba
wm
wm
ba
ba
wm
wm
20
20
wm
wm
20
20
14
14
20
20
```

or in a more readable form:

```
awk '{
         a[NR]=$1
     }
     END {
         for (i=1;i<NR;i++) 
             for (j=0;j<=2;j++) 
                 printf "%s\n%s\n", a[i+j%2],a[i+j%2]
     }'  file
```